# Sencha Unable to locate supported Framework on windows

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm new to Sencha. I tried to install the cmd and to generate a new app but the error `Unable to locate supported Framework` pops out. I've tried to set the system variable to the sencha sdk folder path but doesn't work anyway. The command that I write is this:
`sencha -sdk C:/Users/JohnDoe/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.3.0.19/ generate app myApp C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\sencha`. Then the errors I get are these:

[ERR] Unable to locate supported Framework

```
  Please ensure this command was executed from a supported framework
  directory or that a framework directory was specified via the -sdk switch.
  For example:

      sencha -sdk /path/to/framework-dir generate app AppName path/to/app
```

[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Not a framework directory : C:/Users/JohnDoe/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.3.0.19/

Answer (score 0):

You have added the cmd path instead of extjs sdk.

You would need to get the ExtJs sdk and extract it and replace the sdk path in the above command.

It would be like as shown below

sencha -sdk="D:\Work\ExtJsStuff\ext-7.2.0\ext-7.2.0" generate app SampleApp ./